# Why does MultiTenantConnectionProvider need getAnyConnection method

Tags: java, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am implementing a multitenancy in my application with use of Hibernate ORM library.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy

A few methods in MultiTenantConnectionProvider are not really clear to me:
getAnyConnection and releaseAnyConnection. The docs say only this:

> Hibernate uses these methods during startup to perform various configuration, mainly via the java.sql.DatabaseMetaData object.

To find out what this means I implemented these methods - any connection in my case was a connection to a meta database. I expected to see some metadata created in this database. But in fact Hibernate created the structure the same as in other real tenant databases. No meta data at all.

So why does it need this database?